# Listbox returns index as integer, but I want the current string value

Tags: vba, forms

In this case, I want to store in the txtCountryQuery variable the currently selected country with the currentCountry variable name as String, for example, Brazil. But not, the number of the list index, I want to store it but as text, returning the corresponding country. Attached is part of my code.

Code:

```
'other subroutine
    lbCountry.List = regionArray
    lbCountry.ListIndex = 0

End Sub

'''Main code:
Private Sub lbCountry_Click()

        Dim currentCountry As String
        currentCountry = lbCountry.ListIndex
        rsRegion.MoveFirst
        rsRegion.Move (currentCountry)
        txtCountryQuery = currentCountry

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cycle through the items in the list box. You grab the actual content, by reading out the columns that are there. Here an example that would add the items to a dictionary object:

```
For i = 0 To lbCountry.ListCount - 1
    If Not dict.Exists(lbCountry.Column(1, i)) Then
        dict.Add lbCountry.Column(1, i), i
    End If
Next i
```